# Display Jquery UI dialog after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, settimeout

I have a jquery dialog box that I want to pop up 30 seconds after the user goes to the page.

My Code for the dialog is:

```
    <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#dialog).dialog(
              {
                  width: "300",
                    height: "280",
                  modal: true,

                    resizable: false,
                    closeOnEscape: true ,
                    open: function(){
                        jQuery('.ui-widget-overlay, #dialog-survey').bind('click',function(){
                            jQuery('#dialog').dialog('close');
                        })
                    }
              });

      $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide()  

      $(".survey_link").bind("click", function() {

          var now = new Date();
          var time = now.getTime();
          time += 3600 * 1000;
          now.setTime(time);


          document.cookie='CLK=YES;expires=' + now.toUTCString() + ';path=/';
        });
  });
</script>
```

I've seen code about how to clase after X seconds, and have tried to play around with it to make the dialog open after x seconds, but havent been able. What Do I need for that? Thanks!

Comment: Look into the JavaScript `setTimeout` function. Also you have a typo at `$("#dialog)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    }, 30000);
};
```

Comment: Hi. I've been trying the code but I guess I'm not doing it right. I know its missing a parenthesis at the end, but besides, I've put it above and bellow my code. #dialog is <div id="dialog"></div> right now, I tried making display:none also, but nothing works. Any idea? Thanks!